# XML Dialect for scripting robot tasks

Tags: c#, xml, scripting, robotics, manipulators

In my next project I will have to implement an automation solution to test a hardware device. basically, the test involves an industrial robotic arm picking a device to be tested, holding it at some specified position and then using a series of other devices like motors and sensors  to exercise several areas of the product to be tested.

So my test automation solution will need to communicate with several controllers, either issuing actuation commands or getting information from sensors.

The first idea that comes to mind is to define the sequence of steps for each controller in a custom XML language. In this language I'd need to define primitives such as "MOVE", "IF", "WAIT", "SIGNAL" and etc. These primitives would be used to define the operation script for each controller. Each controller runs asynchronous but eventually gets synchronized, so that's the need for things like "WAIT" and "SIGNAL".

I did a basic search on google and the only thing I was able to find was really old stuff (I don't need to comply to industrial standards, it's a small venture) or XML dialects that were designed for something else.

Question is - do you know of any XML standard that I could use instead of creating my own?

**EDIT:** I'm currently investigating a plan execution language by NASA that looks promising. Name is [PLEXIL](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/plexil/index.php?title=Overview). If anybody knows anything about it, please feel to contribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you reviewed [PARSL](http://www2.parc.com/spl/projects/modrobots/polybot/parc/doc/tutorial/index.html)? It's an XML based robotic scripting language which incorporates sensors, looping, and conditional behavior.

Comment: I had seen it and got some ideas from there. I'm not sure if it is at the right level of abstraction in my case, it seemed to granular for me, but I will take another look. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

XML can be amended to create your 'own standard'.  You can define things using a DTD (Document Type Definition) file.  In this manner you can create your own way the XML has to look like.

The DTD is a schema that contains the structure and constraints you want to put on your XML file.  Have a look [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_schema) on wikipedia for more info.

Hope this is helpful!

Comment: Tony, if I have to define my own XML standard, I'll probably use XSDs instead of the aged DTD, I think I'm ok in that area.
I think what I meant to ask was if there is any already defined dialect that deals with the specific domain of robotic task scheduling.

Comment: @Pedu, unfortunately I have no knowledge of that.  Sorry :(